# DockerHub and GitHub similarities

Tags: docker, dockerhub

What are the differences between DockerHub and GitHub? Can DockerHub replace GitHub or is it only for the Images? If yes, how it is different from Nexus and other binary management tools?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming

Answer (score 9):

Smells like homework :)

They're entirely though for different purposes. GitHub is mainly though for code management, and DockerHub is though for container build, management and distribution (although not very reliable at the moment).

GitHub, indeed, went ahead of that mainly purpose of code management and now offers plenty of interesting features, but it will never be able to substitute DockerHub.

Regarding the opposite (DockerHub replacing GitHub), it is not possible at all because of the previously explained purposes. Perhaps you are thinking about some specific feature both offer, but at the moment it's definitely not something that is going to happen.

There are alternatives to DockerHub for container images distribution and building, and, by experience, far better. The only thing that makes DockerHub interesting at the moment is that it's the simplest and more intuitive platform for managing the whole process of distributing an image. Also, it's managed by Docker inc. itself, so everyone has to deal with it, tangentially or not.

If you feel like I did not get your point, feel free to comment and i'll edit this post!

See ya through the interwebz

Answer (score -1):

Well, the comment by David didn't age well. GitHub does offer a [container registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry).

I can see this is an old comment, but this should be a lesson in absolute statements.